# Open MS Word document model as new document using C#

Tags: c#, ms-word

I try to open and edit MS Word models. This works all fine but I get stuck on a little detail. If a word model (`*.dotx`) is double clicked it opens a new document of the model. If you want to save it, it asks you where to save. If you right click on a word document model you can choose "Open" and then it opens the model directly. And then it won't ask you where to save because it overwrites the existing model. Now I use this C# code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = app.Documents.Open(path, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);

    doc.Content.Text = textBox1.Text;

    doc.Close();
    app.Quit();
}
```

This code opens the document and write some text in it. And then it saves it directly and overwrites the model. So it doesn't open a new document but it opens directly the model.

And now I want to know if it's possible to open it as a new instance of the model and not as the model document itself.

Suggestion apreciated :)

Comment: So basically you want to open a new document but with the contents of an existing document? Can't you just open a new document and copy the contents of the existing document into the new one?

Comment: Thats what I already tried but if I open the document with my C# code it opens the model directly, not a document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `app.Documents.Add(pathToTemplateFile)`. Documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhf98b5c.aspx

Note: You don't need to specify all that optional paramters if you are using .NET 4.0 or higher.

Comment: Oh, this seems to be the right way. Do you know if it's possible to don't open a saveFileDialog? Instead of open a sFD it should open another program. Or this not possible?

Comment: @Therk Please create a new question on SO if you need information that isn't directly related to this question. And provide more information, because I don't understand what you want to do.